# Did Hebrew writing evolve from Egyptian hieroglyphs?

Tags: historical-linguistics, evolution, written-language, evolutionary-linguistics

I read somewhere that the Hebrew writing system evolved from Egyptian pictographs. If that's the case, have anyone read about records that trace exact evolution from a pictograph to a Hebrew letter, or is this something very hard to research because of the lack of historical data?

Comment: You probably want to look at Daniels and Bright, _[The World's Writing Systems](http://www.amazon.com/Worlds-Writing-Systems-Peter-Daniels/dp/0195079930)._

Comment: Even though I'd love to follow this question, orthographies aren't appropriate for the Linguistics SE ([see faq](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/faq)).

Comment: It's discussing the evolution of writing systems, which seems to be of relevant interest to me. There are many potentially interesting linguistic aspects to this question, which a good answer will elucidate.

Comment: Exactly where does the faq say that orthographies aren't appropriate?

Comment: @Knitter - out of curiosity, why is this question relevant to you? My ultimate purpose in learning the evolution is to be able to easier remember Hebrew letters coming from Cyrillic/Latin background, for example.

Comment: @jlawler - thanks so much for the book reference, this is the book I had in mind with this question.

Comment: From the FAQ: "Questions about any natural language" -- which in most academic settings means spoken language. You're not even asking about written language, but the development of an orthography. Don't get me wrong, TOTALLY COOL, just not here. Pretty sure other orthography questions have been closed.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that it's about the writing system, not the language. That was already implicit but I thought I'd make it explicit as there's often confusion on SE between 'language' and writing system.

Comment: I felt the title was a bit nonsensical (how can a language evolve from a writing system) so adjusted it a little.

Comment: In fact whether writing systems are on-topic here was specifically discussed back in September under **[Would questions about writing systems be off-topic?](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11/would-questions-about-writing-systems-be-off-topic)** and the decision was overwhelmingly that they are on-topic. If the FAQ doesn't say so either it must be amended or the question must be revisited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikipedia has [a chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Hebrew_alphabet#Ancestral_scripts_and_script_variants) showing the Hebrew (and other) alphabets and the theorized relation to Egyptian hieroglyphs.

Evidently the [Proto-sinaitic script](http://www.ancientscripts.com/protosinaitic.html) is conjectured to be [intermediate between the hieroglyphs and later true alphabets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_alphabet#Semitic_alphabet), basing most of its letterforms off of equivalent hieroglyphs according to [acrophony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrophony). But it's not clear to me that this link between the hieroglyphs and the Proto-sinaitic script is well-established.